# C++: How to properly delete array of pointers to pointers in class destructor

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, destructor

I am having trouble understanding how to write the destructor in the second class of the program below:

```
class First
{
    // Assume this is a virtual class
};

class Second
{
    private:
        int index;
        First **arr;

    public:
        Second(int size)
        {
            index = 0;
            arr = new First*[size]; // Please bear with my use of new
        }

        ~Second() {}

        void add(First *f)
        {
            arr[index++] = f;
        }
};
```

In all of the similar questions I found, each element of the array is assigned a value dynamically, using new as such: `arr[i] = new First();` . However, here the elements are assigned the value of a pointer to an object that is a parameter of the function. So, should the destructor delete every element one by one and then delete the array, or is ti enough to delete the array?

```
~Second()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < index; ++i) delete[] arr[i]; // Is this necessary?
    delete[] arr;
}
```

Comment: `arr` was `new[]`-ed, so it should be `detele[]`-ed. Was `arr[i]` `new[]`-ed?

Comment: @Barry I guess not, but I'm not sure. Does it need to be deleted only if new was explicitly used?

Comment: Replace `First **arr` with `std::vector<First*>` or, if `Second` owns the `First`s, with `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<First>>`.

Comment: It depends on how the pointers `f` were created, `new`, `new[]`, `malloc`, or `&variable`? And also on whether the code calling `add` will retain ownership and delete the objects later. *"Painting yourself into a corner"* is a phrase that comes to mind.

Comment: Using the backspace key I guess, but other methods may work too, depending on your editor. There's no place for naked `new` 'd arrays or pointers in a modern C++ program.

Comment: @BoPersson So how should the destructor look like in each case? Thanks.

Comment: @n.m. I am aware of that (hence the comment), but this is for schoolwork, and that was the demonstrated way to do it.

Comment: @DimK - It would have to be a matching call to `delete`, `delete[]`, `free`, or *nothing*. But if you don't know what the caller does, you cannot write it.  :-)

Comment: A component (e.g. a class) should `delete` every pointer it `new` s, `delete[]` every pointer it `new[]` s, and leave all other pointers alone. That is, unless there exists a specific, ideally well-documented, agreement to *transfer object ownership* between it and some other component.

Comment: @n.m. So, since I didn't explicitly use `new[]` for each element, there is no need to `delete[]` each one? From what I understood by reading all the comments, it depends on the parameter f. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on **what you and whoever is calling `add` agreed to do**. Who is providing a component that is calling `add`? You need to book a meeting with that person and clarify the responsibilities of your class.

Comment: @n.m. What exactly would that "agreement" entail? And there is no other person (but I guess you know that). Thanks for being patient!

Comment: No I wouldn't know that there's no other person. You have said you are not sure how that pointer is allocated. Why are you unsure if you are the one who is doing it? If you are writing the entire program you need to decide which pointers are **owning** objects they point at and which ones are not. There must be exactly one owning pointer for every object at any given moment in time (though different pointers may own it at different moments, but you better avoid that situation). **You** assign that role. `arr` owns the array of pointers. What owns objects pointed to by array elements?

Comment: @n.m. I'm sorry for the misunderstanding. I should have clarified that my assignment was only to write the class, which was then tested by my school's grading system, using a program that I don't have access to. Regardless, I'm not sure what you mean by "owning". If it means that the pointers from the array are the only ones pointing to the objects, then yes, let's assume that's the case. Thanks again.

Comment: Such things are not assumed, they are agreed upon explicitly and written down. If your assignment says nothing about who should delete the objects, then it is badly written and you probably should try to clarify what they have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In all of the similar questions I found, each element of the array is assigned a value dynamically, using new as such: `arr[i] = new First();` . However, here the elements are assigned the value of a pointer to an object that is a parameter of the function. So, should the destructor delete every element one by one and then delete the array, or is it enough to delete the array?

That, we *cannot* answer. Does `Second` take ownership of the objects passed to `.add()`, and if so how were they allocated?

1. If it does not take ownership, just deleting the array is enough, and that array should be managed by a `std::unique_ptr` doing so for you.
2. If it does take ownership, that argument to `.add()` should be the smart-pointer with the right ownership-semantics and deleter. Your array should then be an array of those smart-pointers, managed by a `std::unique_ptr`.

In either case, if you properly use smart-pointers, the default-dtor is fine.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for replying. Is the use of smart pointers the only proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

You'd better keep NULLs in the array after allocation in the constructor first.

```
    int arr_size; // you need to define this for the reference in destructor

    Second(int size)
    {
        arr_size = size;
        arr = new First*[size]; // Please bear with my use of new
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            arr[i] = NULL;
    }
```

Then, in the destructor, delete the element only if it's not NULL as below.

```
    ~Second()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr_size; i++)
            if (arr[i]) 
                delete arr[i];
        delete[] arr;
    }
```

Comment: Did you miss `index`, and how it is used?

Comment: @Deduplicator, no I left the usage of `index` for `add()` to count the real number of elements in the array as it is.